# pg_search multisearch STI using base class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pg-search

I am building a review site where users can review multiple types of businesses.  The businesses are stored using STI and users have their own model.  I want to implement a single search bar where people can search for users or businesses.  Enter pg_search

```
module Business
  class Venue < Base
    include PgSearch
    multisearchable :against => [:name, :address, :locality, :region]
  end
end

module Business
  class Service < Base
    include PgSearch
    multisearchable :against => [:name, :address, :locality, :region]
  end
end
```

The user model is not important here.  The problem is that pg_search uses Business::Base as the searchable type for all business subclasses.

```
PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(Business::Venue)
```

returns

```
(0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "pg_search_documents" (searchable_type, searchable_id, content, created_at, updated_at)
SELECT 'Business::Base' AS searchable_type, ...
```

Is there a way to specify searchable_type in my models or is there a reason why this can not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a second parameter (boolean) to `rebuild` method that will prevent it from removing all your records.

```
def rebuild(model, clean_up=true)                                                                                                                                                                           
  model.transaction do                                                                                                                                                                                      
    PgSearch::Document.where(:searchable_type => model.base_class.name).delete_all if clean_up                                                                                                              
    Rebuilder.new(model).rebuild                                                                                                                                                                            
  end                                                                                                                                                                                                       
end
```

So if you have multiple inherited models you could do something like this:

```
PgSearch::Document.where(searchable_type: 'Business::Base').delete_all
PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(Business::Venue, false)
PgSearch::Multisearch.rebuild(Business::Service, false)
```